# when removing index.php from url ( codeigniter ) .htaccess Prevent the files from the display

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter, and I tried to remove index.php from url by creating .htaccess file
and it contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

this way is working will at xampp server.
but when I uploaded the site, unfortunately there was a problem appeared:

**I have a folder called files and it content sub folders: images, css, js, swf, upload.
and every file at those folders can't view, and the browser said there the file not found.**

any help ploese.

Comment: what the error log tells you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one which i think will solve your problem ..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|files\/images|files\/css|files\/js|files\/swf|files\/upload)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

you have to tell your server not to handle those directories over to index.php and the line which work for this is :

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|files\/images|files\/css|files\/js|files\/swf|files\/upload)
```

Comment: thanks all I used the last one and worked file. but should I put all sub-directories? because I have another site that I have a folder with alot of sub-directories and I tried to put just the name of the main directory that exist near index.php and it dosn't worked.

Comment: yes you should have to include all of the subfolders / folders that you dont want php to handle ..

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you exclude those too:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|swf|upload)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my .htaccess file. My understanding is that for any file or directory which has access attempted and doesn't exist, it will forward onto Codeigniter.

Anything which does exist will work fine and will not require individual exclusion. This will save time and hassel each time you add a new directory or folder as it wont require you to edit this file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Works for us, but my understanding may well be incorrect. Hope it helps

Comment: thank you. this worked fine. 
I have another website and next index.php I have a folder called files, and this one content alot of folders should I have to put all names of them and names of sub-directories in them?

Comment: not sure why this is not more upvoted, it's the best solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my .htaccess file - which should work for you:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the default file for indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # activate URL rewriting
    RewriteEngine on

    # do not rewrite links to the documentation, assets and public files
    RewriteCond $1 !^(files|css|js|swfimages|assets|uploads|captcha)

    # do not rewrite for php files in the document root, robots.txt or the maintenance page
    RewriteCond $1 !^([^\..]+\.php|robots\.txt|crossdomain\.xml|maintenance\.html)

    # but rewrite everything else
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

thank you. this worked fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have another website and next index.php I have a folder called files, and this one content alot of folders should I have to put all names of them and names of sub-directories in them?